# Retrieve a Call's Web Request Details via API

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-api

On Twilio's website, in the console, you can view a call's Call Details, displaying call information, as well as the GET/POST requests made during the call in the "Request Inspector" section.

**I would like to programmatically retrieve Request Inspector details for MANY calls, through Twilio's API.** This way I can easily compare request times for calls.

I already have an application that retrieves the information seen under "Call Details", but this application and its associated methods/objects do not appear to have a way to access Request Inspector related information.

Is there any way to retrieve this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As far as I am aware, there is no way to retrieve that information through the API.

Comment: would love it if you took a look at my chrome extension that makes the request inspector a little more friendly for debugging purposes - https://github.com/vongillern/twilio-call-request-inspector

Answer (score 0):

I too wanted this. Was sad to see @philnash say that it isn't available. If you're feeling dedicated/persistent. You can pull the json that the twilio request inspector uses. You can bring up the chrome dev tools console, paste the following js into it and then inspect the responseObj. I'm looking at making a chrome extension for this. Personally, I want to see want a much more compact way of seeing what urls got hit, and what digits and/or speechinput twilio recognized. I'm tired of having to drill into a treeview a million times over AND being drowned with info I don't care about (such as the CallerCity, ToCity, AccountSid, etc, etc).

I have a chrome extension that is pretty usable right now. Waiting for some hangup getting it published, but you can sideload it as a dev. All the important bits are in script.js

https://github.com/vongillern/twilio-call-request-inspector